# How to scroll a multiline EditText with the content of a ScrollView?

Tags: android, user-interface

Is it possible to scroll both, a multiline `EditText` and the content of a `ScrollView` when the `EditText` is inside the `ScrollView`?

I came across several solutions but none of them seems to have a user-friendly behavior like web browsers (scrolling would scroll the EditText until the end is reached, and the further scrolling would scroll the ScrollView instead).

Comment: certainly is, and could be done by creating a custom edit text in which you override the dispatchTouchEvent method

Comment: I am tired of duplicating the post here and there using different ID, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762693/how-to-scroll-a-multiline-edittext-with-the-content-of-a-scrollview

Comment: Could not understand why so many upvotes. Selfie?

Comment: @David What do you mean? That link goes back to this question..